# Print the current (wrong) data in an Ajv error message

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I wish to make Ajv print the piece of my data that is wrong when an error is detected.

I'll make a couple of examples of how Ajv currently behaves and how I wish for it to act:

---

###### Example 1

- schema: `{const:"hello!"}`
- data: `"hi"`
- error reported by Ajv: `data must be equal to constant`
- error I wish to see: `data ("hi") must be equal to constant ("hello!")`

###### Example 2

- schema: `{type:"object", properties:{"x":{}}, additionalProperties:false}`
- data: `{x:1, y:2}`
- error reported by Ajv: `data must NOT have additional properties`
- error I wish to see: `data must NOT have additional properties (found "y")`

---

And so on and so forth. I want more information to help me debug my data for any kind of error, anywhere in the data.

I found lots of information pointing to the ajv-errors package but couldn't figure out how to use it to achieve what I want.

Could anyone suggest if it's possible to achieve what I want and how?

Comment: Did you look in the [documentation](https://ajv.js.org/)?  (hint: there is a section in the FAQ about changing the output formats.)